# Take a photo from web camera ans save it on server

Tags: javascript, java

I want to take a photo, send it to server and the save it on disk.

JavaScript function to get photo as blob:

```
takePhoto() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var video = document.getElementById('video');

  document.getElementById("snap").addEventListener("click", function() {
    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);
  });
  let cp = this.contextPath
  canvas.toBlob(blob => {
    this.saveImage({contextPath: cp, image: blob})
  }, 'image/jpeg')
},
```

and on server:

```
File f = new File("IMAGE.jpeg");
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
        f.createNewFile();
        fos.write(file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Where `f` is an array of bytes I get from frontend

File is created but when I try to open it any image viewers or editors say that they cannot open this file. For example, paint:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't save the file directly to server, so you're just creating an empty jpeg file... You should post your base64 blob to server and write to a file there.

Comment: Do you think this is answer? Can't you post this as comment?

Comment: This you can post as a comment also right? otherwise edit this answer and post it with the corrected code

Comment: I did not mentioned in my post, but I send POST request to the server with byte[] as a body. And then save it to the disk. Sorry for that